# How to configure local kubectl to connect to kubernetes EKS cluster

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, amazon-eks

I am very new at kubernetes.

I have created a cluster setup at AWS EKS

Now I want to configure kubectl at a local ubuntu server so that I can connect at AWS EKS cluster.

Need to understand the process. [ If at all it is possible ]

Answer (score 8):

aws cli is used to create Kubernetes config (normally `~/.kube/config`).

See details by:
`aws eks update-kubeconfig help`

Answer (score 4):

You can follow this [guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/managing-auth.html). You need to do following steps.

1.Installing kubectl

2.Installing aws-iam-authenticator

3.Create a kubeconfig for Amazon EKS

4.Managing Users or IAM Roles for your Cluster

Also take a look at configuring kubeconfig using AWS CLI [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/getting-started-console.html#eks-configure-kubectl)

Comment: Thanks a lot .. missed the documentation .. done now

Answer (score 0):

You can use `aws eks update-kubeconfig` command. However, you may need to update mapUsers on configMap/aws-auth for mapping userarn and Kubernetes roles.

> kubectl edit -n kube-system configmap/aws-auth

```
aws eks update-kubeconfig --name <Clustername> --region=us-central-1 --profile <aws profile>
```